# 64GB compact flash not booting up in DOS

Tags: ms-dos, boot

I have purchased a 64GB compact flash UDMA card and am unable to boot up in DOS.

The machine I'm running has a Pentium 1.6Ghz process in it just to give you an idea about how "modern" it is compared to say, a 486. The BIOS can see the drive fine.

If I boot the machine using a Windows 98 SE floppy disk (or even a DOS6.22 boot disk), DOS can see the drive perfectly and I can easily work with files.

I have run clearhdd.exe and fdisk.exe to set the drive up, which worked without any problems at all. After that, I used the `format c: /s` command which successfully worked and copied the files across.

When the machine boots up though, I get a black screen with a blinking cursor, that's it. I have successfully used a 4GB CF card with this same machine and it booted fine which leads me to believe it's the CF card, however, DOS can see it perfectly.

I suspect that it's not booting because it's looking at the wrong "sector" or part of the disk responsible for booting? I'm not sure.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the card programmed with an MBR with boot code? Did you run "fdisk /MBR" to rewrite the boot code to sector 0 ?

Comment: Pentium 1.6 GHz? You mean 166 MHz, don't you? The fastest straight Pentium topped at 120 MHz, Pentium MMX at 255 MHz. It wasn't until the **Pentium IV** that1.6 Ghz were reached. Making this a mid naughties machine and rather borderline (and beyond the lifetime of Win98).

Comment: @Raffzahn I had a non-MMX Pentium 200, and it looks like there were also pre-MMX 0.35µm runs at 133Mhz, 150Mhz and 166Mhz. All Socket 7, mostly released in 1996. Probably I've misunderstood what counts as a straight Pentium. Definitely I've decided to run off into the long grass with this irrelevant response.

Comment: @Tommy Well, I tried to draw a line on before MMX but yeah, it's a blurry one. And you're right, there was the P54CS with 66 MHz and up to 3.0 multiplier, but AFAIK only available for direct soldering, like in laptops. Then again, They cranked out everything imaginable to hold against AMD, so yeah, maybe there were PGA versions as well.

Comment: @Raffzahn I have a pre-MMX, 200MHz PGA socket 7 Pentium, so yes, they were available as desktop CPUs at that speed ;-). The MMX version went up to 233MHz.

Comment: @StephenKitt I stand corrected. It was a time of much variation, wasn't it?

Comment: big size for MS-DOS have you tried [EZ-Drive](https://www.philscomputerlab.com/western-digital.html#) ? What FS file system you have? What version of MS-DOS? Also PQ magic (I think PQ8 was for MS-DOS too) sometimes helps to fix booting problems (MBR,...)... Have you checked the BIOS Setup boot settings?

Comment: @Spektre I've tried GDISK, PQ8 for DOS, fdisk...I think it's the CF card which is the problem.

Comment: @VincePanuccio there where quite a few HDD size barriers in the old times some related to BIOS, some to MS-DOS some to non LBA and your CF crosses them all Try EZ-Drive first (that usually fix em all)... Hope you are connecting directly to IDE not through USB  ...  Also Which MS-DOS as 6.22 do not know FAT32 without  special drivers hence not possible to boot with ... versions 7.0++ are capable of booting and knowing FAT32 but that is not fully compatible with 6.22. If nothing works create a small FAT16 primary partition ignoring rest of the CF space ...

Comment: OK, so the EZ-BIOS that EZ-Drive installed "boots" into that custom book loader so I'm thinking now that the CF card is fine since it can boot into custom code. It's just DOS that isn't working so I'll try formatting the partitions as FAT and let you know what happens.

Comment: So looks like DOS is the problem here. I created a FAT partition of only 1GB and it still doesn't boot, however, EZ-BIOS does boot. I think there's something going on with DOS compatibility here. I might try installing the GRUB bootloader to see if I can then point to a dos partition and then boot off of that.

Comment: there use to be a dos utility you could run and would detect the heads/cylinders of unknown IDE drives, or even compact flash, I wish i could remember the name of it, like IDEwalker or something like that. anyone?

Comment: During the early 1990s MS DOS would only handle hard drive partitions up to 32 GB in size, whereas UNIX systems had no such limitations. It might be an overhang from that era.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Out of all the things I tried, what ended up working was:

Copy Windows 98 set up files to the CF card. Let windows do it's thing, and boom, it booted from the CF card.

Answer (score 6):

1. Check the [MBR record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record). Did you use the "fdisk /MBR" command?
2. Some of those cards do not support the [CHS mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector) (Cylinder / Head / Sector), especially the larger ones. Try the smaller card.
3. Check if the BIOS supports the LBA mode. Some older BIOSes can't...

Generally, booting from the hard disk (or CF in this case) perform reading MBR from the very first sector of the disk. There is a small routine (just a few hundreds of bytes), which looks into the master partition table (it is a part of MBR too), find a bootable partition, reads its boot sector and perform a boot code from this sector. Reading the very first sector should be easy, but maybe there is a problem finding the bootable partition.

Comment: `fdisk /MBR` has not solved the problem, which is unfortunate. I'll see if a 32GB card works, and keep reducing the size until I find the magic number. The BIOS definitely supports LBA. Whether or not the CF card supports CHS mode is irrelevant right now because it's obvious to me that it's the card, not the hardware or the MBR. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I've run into that issue before.  Try a smaller card.  Some systems do not like to boot off of cards greater than 16 GB.  Some 32 GB...

Comment: Follow-up query: would it be safe to assume such systems are failing even to load the boot sector?

Comment: With Socket 7 era machines, that could indeed happen - around 2000, an 8GB hard drive was *massive*, many BIOSes could not really handle >32GB when they came out.